# Event emitter inside of event emitter using socket.io node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i have a situation where i have web-socket server and OSC message client. I need to send data to all socket users when i recieve a message from OSC server. So far i just placed the OSC event inside of socket.io connection function, thus it created a memory leak. Because it create a new event emitter for the global variable "oscServer". How do i avoid that?

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var oscServer = new osc.Server(oscPorts.server, oscIp.server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  oscServer.on(oscAdress.server, function (msg, rinfo) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('moved', msg);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try saving a reference to `socket`, the only caveat - you'll need to ensure that `var socket` isn't `undefined`, so I would use a `promise` to make sure that socket is defined before broadcasting your event.

```
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 var oscServer = new osc.Server(oscPorts.server, oscIp.server);
 var socket;

  io.on('connection', function (s) {
    socket = s;
 });

  oscServer.on(oscAdress.server, function (msg, rinfo) {
     socket.broadcast.emit('moved', msg);
   });
```

Comment: But wouldn't the socket variable be changed when the next user connect to frontend? Or it just recreate the variable, thus still allowing to broadcast emit messages?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should be a new instance.

Comment: You could also try `io.sockets.broadcast.emit( 'moved', msg )`